# Will Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 upgrade to the standard Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, upgrade, ubuntu-gnome, 18.04

With the end of Ubuntu GNOME and the adoption of GNOME by the standard Ubuntu, will Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 upgrade to the standard Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: As answered it will, whether an upgrade is successful is at best 50:50 at this point. If you have any ppa's, use ppa-purge, if using prop video drivers remove, if multiple sessions are installed remove all but gnome-session before trying an upgrade to increase chances..

Comment: @doug maybe I'm lucky, but I have updated to the 18.04 Beta without any issues. And I have tons of PPA, mixed video drivers, i3wm, GNOME Xorg and GNOME Wayland.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, by default it will. Please see the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes). There you can also see that it's easy to keep using a desktop closer to vanilla GNOME, if you like, by installing `gnome-session` and `vanilla-gnome-desktop`, then choose GNOME on the login screen.

Comment: The Ubuntu GNOME flavor has been discontinued. If you are using "Ubuntu GNOME, you will be upgraded to Ubuntu. Choose the Ubuntu session from the cog on the login screen if you would like the default Ubuntu experience. " Thank you so much for the quick answer.